# Google Sheets Merge

Tags: google-apps-script, merge, google-sheets

I am attempting to merge spreadsheets in a folder into a single master document. The following script works except for it splits each spreadsheet into a new sheet on the master document. Is it possible to merge them into a single sheet?

```
 function myFunction() {

  /* Retrieve the desired folder */
  var myFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1RyWUxYLMuOvYUuooy7f41w1zMGntGmg7");

  /* Get all spreadsheets that resided on that folder */
  var spreadSheets = myFolder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");

  /* Create the new spreadsheet that you store other sheets */  
  var newSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Merged Sheets");

  /* Iterate over the spreadsheets over the folder */
  while(spreadSheets.hasNext()) {

    var sheet = spreadSheets.next();

    /* Open the spreadsheet */
    var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet.getId());

    /* Get all its sheets */
    for(var y in spreadSheet.getSheets()) {

      /* Copy the sheet to the new merged Spread Sheet */
      spreadSheet.getSheets()[y].copyTo(newSpreadSheet); 
    }
  }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the values out of each sheet tab and then set the values in one sheet tab.  Get the number of rows to write and the number of columns to write from the retrieved data.  See the comments on each line of code.

```
 function myFunction() {
  var allSheets,i,L,lastRow,shData,targetTab,thisTab;

  /* Retrieve the desired folder */
  var myFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1RyWUxYLMuOvYUuooy7f41w1zMGntGmg7");

  /* Get all spreadsheets that resided on that folder */
  var spreadSheets = myFolder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");

  /* Create the new spreadsheet that you store other sheets */  
  var newSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Merged Sheets");

  /* Iterate over the spreadsheets over the folder */
  while(spreadSheets.hasNext()) {

    var sheet = spreadSheets.next();

    /* Open the spreadsheet */
    var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet.getId());
    allSheets = spreadSheet.getSheets();//Get all sheet tabs in this spreadsheet file

    /* Get all its sheets */
    L = allSheets.length;//How many sheet tabs are in this spreadsheet

    targetTab = spreadSheet.getSheets()[0];//Get the first sheet tab in the target sheet

    for(i=0;i<L;i++) {//Loop through all the sheet tabs
      thisTab = allSheets[i];//Get this sheet tab
      shData = thisTab.getDataRange().getValues();//Get all values in the sheet tab
      lastRow = targetTab.getLastRow();//Get current last row in the sheet tab

      targetTab.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, shData.length, shData[0].length).setValue(shData);//Set the values at the end
    }
  }      
}
```